# How can i make exception handler to avoid of hanging my system when the font is not supported?

Tags: c#, fonts

I have written this code to select a font from my list and creates a character with that font. but for some fonts I get the following error

```
"Font 'Magneto' does not support style 'Regular'."
```

Does anyone know how to add an exception to handle this error and for example jumps to the next font or shows me a error pop-up that we can select a different font?

```
Font myFont = new Font(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 60);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried try/catch?

```
try
{
    //your code
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //do something else
}
```

This way your application won't crash when an exception occurs while running a piece of code and instead does something else, like alerting the user or maybe setting a default font.

**Update**

```
void SetFont(Font font)
{
    //the relevant code
}

try
{
    //other stuff
    SetFont(font);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    SetFont(anotherFont);
}
```

This is how I was thinking you could do. I don't really understand what you mean by not being able to call your methods outside of the try-block. If this doesn't help please show what your code looks like.

Comment: do i need to just to put (Exception) or a specific exception?

Comment: Simply puttin Exception will catch all exceptions. If there are some specific exceptions you want to perform a different action for you catch them first.

Comment: do you know if i can put something in the "catch" to go back to the "try" and run it with the new given value instead of copping the whole code again in my "catch" part?

Comment: You could put the try block around a call to your method and then in the catch just call it again with a different value.

Comment: yes but the methods i declare inside the try block can not be called from out side of try. so i have to put the whole code in try block. (if i am right?)